# Why are all Rails helpers available to all views, all the time? Is there a way to disable this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

Why can I access helper methods for one controller in the views for a different controller? Is there a way to disable this without hacking/patching Rails?

Comment: There is a new, more relevant answer. Check out Craig Walkers answer

Answer (score 108, accepted):

@George Schreiber's method doesn't work as of Rails 3.1; the code has changed significantly.

However, there's now an even better way to disable this feature in Rails 3.1 (and hopefully later). In your config/application.rb, add this line:

```
config.action_controller.include_all_helpers = false
```

This will [prevent ApplicationController from loading all of the helpers](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-1-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/railties/paths.rb#L16).

(For anyone who is interested, [here's the pull request where the feature was created](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/106).)

Comment: I'm on 3.2. Does application.config here mean config/application.rb?

Comment: Will the ApplicationHelper get included as well if I disable include_all_helpers or I need to include it manually?

Comment: @AzizLight I'm not sure, since I haven't tested, that. However, I'd expect so, as ApplicationHelper is intended to be always be available in views as the "root" helper. It's the helpers from unrelated controllers that are of primary issue here.

Comment: I think this should be the default behavior.

Answer (score 100):

The answer depends on the Rails version.

### Rails >= 3.1

Change the `include_all_helpers` config to `false` in any environment where you want to apply the configuration. If you want the config to apply to all environments, change it in `application.rb`.

```
config.action_controller.include_all_helpers = false
```

When false, it will [skip the inclusion](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-1-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/railties/paths.rb#L16).

### Rails < 3.1

Delete the following line from `ApplicationController`

```
helper :all
```

In this way each controller will load its own helpers.

Comment: This line doesn't exist for me in Rails 3.2, so this solution likely no longer applies to later versions of Rails.

Comment: I'd be interested in why this changed so significantly from Rails up version 3.1? Doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: NOTE: The above comments are no longer valid, now that the answer has been updated to include Rails > 3.1

Comment: Note: Your ApplicationHelper will still be loaded. If you'd like to include any specific helpers all of the time, you can add `include HelperName` to the top of your ApplicationHelper.

Comment: works for Rails 4.1, still needed. Why isn't this default ... it's better to include only particular Helpers where needed (as @vansan said)

Answer (score 27):

In Rails 3, `actioncontroller/base.rb` (around line 224):

```
def self.inherited(klass)
  super
  klass.helper :all if klass.superclass == ActionController::Base
end
```

So yes, if you derive your class from `ActionController::Base`, all helpers will be included.

To come around this, call `clear_helpers` (`AbstractClass::Helpers`; included in `ActionController::Base`) at the beginning of your controller's code. Source code comment for clear_helpers:

```
# Clears up all existing helpers in this class, only keeping the helper
# with the same name as this class.
```

E.g.:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  clear_helpers
  ...
end
```

Comment: By the time you call `clear_helpers` the (performance) damage has already been done since all of the helpers have been loaded.  You really want to use `config.action_controller.include_all_helpers = false` (as @Craig Walker states, above), as it prevents the helpers from being loaded in the first place, thus gaining you some performance (perhaps most significantly in development mode).

Thanks for including the `actioncontroller/base.rb` snippet; it's always nice to see code and remove some of the mystery.

Comment: `clear_helpers` is still useful for rails 3.0 - `config.action_controller.include_all_helpers = false` is only rails 3.1 and above.

Answer (score 5):

Actually in **Rails 2**, the default functionality of ActionController::Base was to include all helpers.

[Changeset 6222 on 02/24/07 20:33:47 (3 years ago) by dhh](http://dev.rubyonrails.org/changeset/6222):
Make it a default assumption that you want all helpers, all the time (yeah, yeah)

**change:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base 
  helper :all # include all helpers, all the time 
end
```

As of Rails 3 beta 1, that is no longer the case as noted in the CHANGELOG:

- Added that ActionController::Base now does helper :all instead of relying on the default ApplicationController in Rails to do it [DHH]

Comment: so does that mean in Rails 3, all helpers are by default all the time loaded?

Comment: @Nik surely yes, atleast for 3.2