# Ruby on Rails: Global Helper method for all controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I set up a method that I want accessible from all controllers?

Sticking the method in application_helper just makes it available to the views

Comment: here is another example:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179865/why-are-all-rails-helpers-available-to-all-views-all-the-time-is-there-a-way-t

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can `include ApplicationHelper` in your controllers (or base ApplicationController) to make the helper methods available.

You can also include the following line in your ApplicationController to include all helpers:

```
helper :all
```

Comment: I didn't include ApplicationHelper, but what you said allowed me to create a shared.rb in app/controllers/

Answer (score 38):

You can add the method to `ApplicationController`. All the other controllers subclass `ApplicationController`, so will be able to call the method.

You'll want to make the method `protected` so that it is only visible to subclasses and isn't available as a web-accessible action.

Comment: this is a great approach! + 500

Answer (score 10):

Stick it into `lib`. Helpers are meant to be used in views; if you have application-specific libraries (and by "libraries" I mean any code that your application uses, and by "application-specific" anything that doesn't belong into `vendor`), `lib` is the place to go.

Answer (score 1):

Here is very good example

http://railscasts.com/episodes/64-custom-helper-modules

Answer (score 0):

In rails 3 you can use:  the view_context object in your controller to access view helper methods. For example,

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def some_method
     view_context.some_view_helper_method
   end
end

module ApplicationHelper
  def some_view_helper_method
  end
end
```

Check out this: 
http://wowkhmer.com/2011/09/09/use-view-helper-methods-in-rails-3-controller/