# Provide state to helper from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

Given the following helper:

```
def hide_contact_details!
  @hide_contact_details = true
end

def show_contact_details?
  @!hide_contact_details
end
```

I want to call `hide_contact_details!` from a select few controllers and use `show_contact_details?` around my templates.

However, when I use the `view_context` object from a controller in Rails 3, it seems to point to a different object than my view.

`@hide_contact_details` is nil, unless I call hide_contact_details! from within the view, rather than through `view_context.hide_contact_details!` in the view.

How can I call a (helper)method in the controller, that sets a boolean which is accessible to the helper in the view?

Comment: Perhaps `helper_method` would do the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992659/in-rails-what-exactly-do-helper-and-helper-method-do

Comment: This doesn't work. The problem is not the behavior, the problem is the state. Including the helper in the controller just sets the instance variable on the controller, but the (unknown) object that show_contact_details? is mixed into when called from the view, doesn't contain this instance variable.