# Template error based on undefined method 'custom_helper'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, view-helpers

I have a custom helper in `app/helpers/posts_helpers.rb`:

```
module PostsHelper
  def custom_helper(post)
    #do something
  end
end
```

When I call this from one of views, I get the error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'custom_helper' for class..
```

But if I call the same helper from `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` as follows, then the view is able to detect the helper.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def custom_helper(post)
    #do something
  end
end
```

Even tried setting the include all helper option to true explicitly although it is true by default in `config/application.rb`. That didn't help either.

```
config.action_controller.include_all_helpers = true
```

Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

By default, methods in helpers are available only to their corresponding controllers. For example, `PostsController` has access to methods in the `PostsHelper`, but the various posts views don't. If you want to make those methods available to the views, designate them as `helper_methods`, like so:

```
module PostsHelper

  helper_method :custom_helper

  def custom_helper(post)
    #do something
 end
end
```

In contrast, methods defined in ApplicationHelper are available globally, i.e. in all controllers and views.

You can read the excellent answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992659/in-rails-what-exactly-do-helper-and-helper-method-do) for more detail.

You can also `include` a module in ApplicationHelper to give its methods global accessibility:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  include PostsHelper
  ...

end
```

That's not always a good idea though, because it can make your code difficult to understand and maintain later.

Comment: Thanks for responding. helper_method is for methods under controller. The ones I am asking about here are, from the app/helpers/ folder. These are not available to controllers but available to views by default.