# Calling a method from a controller in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a rails beginner and this simple question is really perplexing me.
On every page, I want a list of all available pages in my app. So in layouts/application.html.erb I have the following code:

```
<ul>
<!-- This loop prints out links to all the pages -->
<% @pages = Page.all %>
<% @pages.each do |page| %>
<li><%= link_to page.name, page_path(page) %></li>
<% end %>
```

This code DOES work, however I am not satisfied with it because it goes against MVC principles. Really instead of querying the database with <% @pages = Page.all %>, I instead want to call the getpages method in the PagesController, which looks like this:

```
def getpages
    @pages = Page.all
end
```

My first instinct was to replace <% @pages = Page.all %> with <% PagesController.getpages %>, which was unsuccessful.
I am confident this problem has something to do with routing, could anyone enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, let me say that your approach is not *that* wrong imho. Introducing an extra method which is just an alias for `Page.all` is not really needed, or not really an improvement.

But there are definitely better approaches.

I would fix this as follows: in `ApplicationController` I would add the method

```
def get_all_pages
  @pages ||= get_all_pages
end
```

This will make sure that any controller knows that method.

Then, if you are sure, you need it on *every* page, you can just a `before_filter` in your `ApplicationController`, but generally, I prefer to write it in the controller itself.

E.g.

```
class IdeasController < ApplicationController

  before_action :get_all_pages

  ... the rest of your controller ... 

end
```

Also, I would extract your list of pages into a partial, store in under `app/views/shared/_pages_list.html.erb` or `app/views/pages/_pages_list.html.erb` and then in your `application.html.erb` just call to render the partial instead.

The method we called sets the instance variable `@pages`, it will be available in the view, so your partial would like:

```
<ul>
  <% @pages.each do |page| %>
    <li><%= link_to page.name, page_path(page) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Lastly, for completeness, let me answer how you can make a controller-method available in the view. In a controller write

```
def get_pages
  # ..do something
end
helper_method :get_pages
```

This will make the method `get_pages` available in the view, but only for a controller that was responsible for loading/rendering that view. So if you want it for all views, define this in `ApplicationController`. E.g. this is what we generally do when defining `current_user` method.

#### Further improvements/alternatives

- if you start to get some more code, extract the code related to the page-list-fetching-and-rendering into a separate module, and include that into your `ApplicationController`. This makes your `ApplicationController` more readable.

  - Note: this is exactly what `concerns` were introduced for, so you can use that, if you are on rails 4
- a `Page` is its own resource, so you could always create a separate `PagesController` and make sure it is responsible for rendering the list, and use ajax to fetch on the pages where it is needed. This is a really nice solution, but also a bit more work (overkill?). But very nicely structured.
- This problem, where you have different areas on a page, which each should have their own Controller-Model-View, is exactly what the [cells gem](https://github.com/apotonick/cells) gem solves in a very clean way. There is a very good example of rendering a shopping-cart on the page I linked, so you could always check that out.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you accomplish this. I'll try to sum them up, but the easiest one is by using a `before_filter` on your controller.

Considering your method is named `get_pages` in the controller, just write:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_pages

  def get_pages
    @pages = Page.all
  end
end
```

Then, on your view, you'll be able to access it as `@pages` on all your controller actions.

Comment: you haven't said how he should access it, which is the part he's having problems with.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [helper method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992659/in-rails-what-exactly-do-helper-and-helper-method-do) like this:

```
#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
Class ApplicationHelper
   def pages
       Page.all
   end
end
```

Helpers are available in your views, so you'll be able to do this:

```
#app/views/application/index.html.erb
<% pages.each do |page| %>
   <%= page.title %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If so, simply add the following code into action in the controller

```
def youraction
  @pages = Page.all
end
```

This will make the global variable @pages available in your view for use. Call it directly as @pages.

Comment: Nope, you did not read the question well. OP wants the list of pages on a number of page.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be using an asynchronous call to load the result of `PagesController#index` and show it inside your application layout.

```
$.ajax("<%= pages_path %>").done(function(html) {
    $("#pages-list").html(html);
});
```

To achieve this you could make `PagesController#index` render with `layout: false` if the `request.xhr?` returns `true`.

Comment: Why the down-vote? This is actually a pretty good approach. At least you define the `pages` in only place and really reuse it.

Comment: Yeah, the downvotes should be motivated at least imho.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the question is coming from a Rails beginner and has nothing to do with ajax. The answer seems almost entirely unrelated to the question - the only thing they have in common is a reference to `pages`.