# Define a new method for a view file in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to Rails and want to achieve the following.

In my view, I have a very verbose set of expressions

```
<% @courses.each do |course| %>
  <%= course.name.squish.downcase.tr(" ","_").gsub(/[^0-9a-z_]/i, '')` %>
<% end %>
```

I want to define a new method called `get_file_name` and replace the second line of the original code with:

`<%= course.get_file_name %>`

Now, I have tried to define the new method in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`, but it did not work.

Also, putting a scope in the `app/models/course.rb` was not successful. I tried to write `scope :course_image, -> { name.squish.downcase.tr(" ","_").gsub(/[^0-9a-z_]/i, '') }`

In php, I would simply define a new function. How can I do this in Rails 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to call the method on an instance of a course, you should define an instance method on that class.

```
class Course
  def get_file_name
    name.squish.downcase.tr(" ","_").gsub(/[^0-9a-z_]/i, '')
  end
end
```

This should allow you to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [ptd's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3945932/ptd)'s answer if you want to call the method on the course instance. Just in case you were really excited to use a helper method you would need to pass the object as a parameter to the helper method:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def get_file_name(course)
    course.name.squish.downcase.tr(" ","_").gsub(/[^0-9a-z_]/i, '')
  end
end
```

And then in your view you would write:

```
<%= get_file_name(course) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Objects**

You have to remember that Rails is [*object orientated*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)

This means that if you're looking to work with methods, you have to appreciate their *relation* to the objects you're hoping them to work on. The important thing to note here is that there are therefore two ways you could create the functionality you desire:

> 1. Create a "helper" method
> 2. Create an "instance" method

I'll explain both for you here:

---

**Helper**

["Helper" methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992659/in-rails-what-exactly-do-helper-and-helper-method-do) are pretty much the same as PHP functions, in that they are ambiguous.

They live in `#app/helpers/[x]_helper.rb`, and look like this:

```
#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
class ApplicationHelper
   def my_method
      ...
   end
end
```

The vital thing to note here is that as helpers are *detached* from your `objects`, you have to send through the data you wish to manipulate. This is very important because, as you'll see in a minute, it means you can use them to process a large variety of different data-sets

Here's how you'd use a helper method in your case:

```
#View
<%= get_file_name course.name %>

#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
class ApplicationHelper
  def get_file_name name
      name.squish.downcase.tr(" ","_").gsub(/[^0-9a-z_]/i, '')
  end
end
```

---

**Instance Method**

The next step is to look at creating an *instance method* for your `Course` model itself.

Because Rails (by virtue of being built on Ruby) is *object orientated*, every `Model` you create is basically an "object". This means that if you wanted to, you could introduce an instance method for each *instance* of that object:

[image]

```
#app/models/course.rb
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
   def get_file_name
      name.squish.downcase.tr(" ","_").gsub(/[^0-9a-z_]/i, '')
   end
end
```

This will allow you to call: `@course.get_file_name`