# Rails return "undefined method" when I call my helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple `FriendsController`

```
class FriendsController < ApplicationController

    helper_method :get_friends_array

    def create

        @bill = Bill.find(params[:bill_id])
        @friend = @bill.friends.build(friend_params)

        if @friend.save
            add_friends_array(@friend.name)
            redirect_to bill_path(@bill)
        else
            redirect_to root_path
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @bill = Bill.find(params[:bill_id])
        @friend = @bill.friends.find(params[:id])
        @friend.destroy
        redirect_to bill_path(@bill)
    end



    # None CRUD methods

    friends_array = Array.new

    def add_friends_array(name)
        friends_array << name
    end

    def get_friends_array
        friends_array
    end

    private

    def friend_params
        params.require(:friend).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

and when I try to call the following line in one of my form in the view `<p><%= f.label :payer %> <%=f.select :payer, options_for_select(get_friends_array)%></p>`
it returns a `undefined local variable or method`get_friends_array'`

Why is that? Is it because I am calling a method within another method? Or is it something else entirely?

thanks!

EDIT: Does it have to do with the fact that the view is not a Friends View? I'm actually calling `get_friends_array` in another Model's view. If that's the case, what's the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is that? Is it because I am calling a method within another
>   method?

No

> Does it have to do with the fact that the view is not a Friends View?
>   I'm actually calling get_friends_array in another Model's view. If
>   that's the case, what's the best way to solve this problem?

Mostly likely yes, the page you are trying to use this helper method might be coming from another controller and not `FriendsController`.

If friend names are coming from your database you should be able to populate array by doing a `pluck`: `Friend.pluck(:name, :id)`

More info about helper methods - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3993323/753705