# Error after migration from ERB to HAML

Tags: ruby, haml, erb

I used http://htmltohaml.com/ this to convert my ERB and there is some kind of problem.

The working ERB before the convert

```
<h3><%= t("admin.labels.employee") %> <%= content_tag(:span, employee_counter) %></h3>
<%
   def create_validation_rules(field_rules)
     Hash[field_rules.map do |rule|
            next ["rule-#{rule[:name]}", rule[:value]] if rule[:value]
            next ["msg-#{rule[:name]}", rule[:msg]] if rule[:msg]
          end] if field_rules
   end
%>
<div class="control-group form-controls">
    <%= f.label :first_name, t("labels.name") %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, placeholder: t("labels.first_name"), class: 'js-employeeName', id: "merchant_employees_attributes_#{index}_first_name", name: "merchant[employees_attributes][#{index}][first_name]", autocomplete: "off", maxlength: 50, size: nil, data: create_validation_rules(validations[:first_name]) %>
    <%= f.text_field :middle_name, placeholder: t("labels.middle_name"), id: "merchant_employees_attributes_#{index}_middle_name", name: "merchant[employees_attributes][#{index}][middle_name]", autocomplete: "off", maxlength: 100, size: nil %>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name, placeholder: t("labels.last_name"), class: 'js-employeeName', id: "merchant_employees_attributes_#{index}_last_name", name: "merchant[employees_attributes][#{index}][last_name]", autocomplete: "off", maxlength: 50, size: nil, data: create_validation_rules(validations[:last_name]) %>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label :email, t("labels.email_address") %>
  <%= f.text_field :email, id: "merchant_employees_attributes_#{index}_email", name: "merchant[employees_attributes][#{index}][email]", autocomplete: "off", maxlength: 250, size: nil, data: create_validation_rules(validations[:email]) %>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <% if force_superuser_role %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :superuser, value: "1" %>
  <% else %>
      <%= f.label :superuser, t("admin.labels.superuser") %>
      <%= f.check_box :superuser, class: "superuser_checkbox", id: "merchant_employees_attributes_#{index}_superuser", name: "merchant[employees_attributes][#{index}][superuser]"%>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Not working HAML after the convert:

This is my error:
Showing /Users/project/app/views/shared/_employee.html.haml where line #9 raised:

```
%h3
  = t("admin.labels.employee")
  = content_tag(:span, employee_counter)
- def create_validation_rules(field_rules)
- Hash[field_rules.map do |rule|
- next ["rule-#{rule[:name]}", rule[:value]] if rule[:value]
- next ["msg-#{rule[:name]}", rule[:msg]] if rule[:msg]
- end] if field_rules
- end
.control-group.form-controls
  = f.label :first_name, t("labels.name")
  = f.text_field :first_name, placeholder: t("labels.first_name"), class: 'js-employeeName', id: "merchant_employees_attributes_#{index}_first_name", name: "merchant[employees_attributes][#{index}][first_name]", autocomplete: "off", maxlength: 50, size: nil, data: create_validation_rules(validations[:first_name])
  = f.text_field :middle_name, placeholder: t("labels.middle_name"), id: "merchant_employees_attributes_#{index}_middle_name", name: "merchant[employees_attributes][#{index}][middle_name]", autocomplete: "off", maxlength: 100, size: nil
  = f.text_field :last_name, placeholder: t("labels.last_name"), class: 'js-employeeName', id: "merchant_employees_attributes_#{index}_last_name", name: "merchant[employees_attributes][#{index}][last_name]", autocomplete: "off", maxlength: 50, size: nil, data: create_validation_rules(validations[:last_name])
.control-group
  = f.label :email, t("labels.email_address")
  = f.text_field :email, id: "merchant_employees_attributes_#{index}_email", name: "merchant[employees_attributes][#{index}][email]", autocomplete: "off", maxlength: 250, size: nil, data: create_validation_rules(validations[:email])
.control-group
  - if force_superuser_role
    = f.hidden_field :superuser, value: "1"
  - else
    = f.label :superuser, t("admin.labels.superuser")
    = f.check_box :superuser, class: "superuser_checkbox", id: "merchant_employees_attributes_#{index}_superuser", name: "merchant[employees_attributes][#{index}][superuser]"
```

Comment: Why are you defining a method inside the view??? You're asking for big trouble here.

Comment: I might suggest defining that function elsewhere, like in a helper or computing that value in the controller. HAML, and ERB aren't really well suited for that purpose.

Comment: @ChaseGilliam Indeed, HAML makes it hard to define a function in a view _because_ functions shouldn't be defined in views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *correct* way to handle this is to define the method as a helper in your controller:

```
class MyController
  helper_method :create_validation_rules

private
  def create_validation_rules(field_rules)
    Hash[field_rules.map do |rule|
      next ["rule-#{rule[:name]}", rule[:value]] if rule[:value]
      next ["msg-#{rule[:name]}", rule[:msg]] if rule[:msg]
    end] if field_rules
  end
end
```

This will allow you to call `create_validation_rules` from within the view, without having to define the method there.  See [In Rails, what exactly do helper and helper_method do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992659/in-rails-what-exactly-do-helper-and-helper-method-do) to understand exactly what a helper method is and how it works.

---

However, if you simply *must* use an embedded method in the View code, there is a solution: you can simply eliminate the last `end` in the inline function, and properly indent the body of the function and the loop.

In this case, the error message would have explained everything:

> You don't need to use "- end" in Haml. Un-indent to close a block

Updating your HAML code, this works:

```
%h3
  = t("admin.labels.employee")
  = content_tag(:span, employee_counter)
- def create_validation_rules(field_rules)
  - Hash[field_rules.map do |rule|
    - next ["rule-#{rule[:name]}", rule[:value]] if rule[:value]
    - next ["msg-#{rule[:name]}", rule[:msg]] if rule[:msg]
  - end] if field_rules
.control-group.form-controls
  = f.label :first_name, t("labels.name")
  = f.text_field :first_name, placeholder: t("labels.first_name"), class: 'js-employeeName', id: "merchant_employees_attributes_#{index}_first_name", name: "merchant[employees_attributes][#{index}][first_name]", autocomplete: "off", maxlength: 50, size: nil, data: create_validation_rules(validations[:first_name])
  = f.text_field :middle_name, placeholder: t("labels.middle_name"), id: "merchant_employees_attributes_#{index}_middle_name", name: "merchant[employees_attributes][#{index}][middle_name]", autocomplete: "off", maxlength: 100, size: nil
  = f.text_field :last_name, placeholder: t("labels.last_name"), class: 'js-employeeName', id: "merchant_employees_attributes_#{index}_last_name", name: "merchant[employees_attributes][#{index}][last_name]", autocomplete: "off", maxlength: 50, size: nil, data: create_validation_rules(validations[:last_name])
.control-group
  = f.label :email, t("labels.email_address")
  = f.text_field :email, id: "merchant_employees_attributes_#{index}_email", name: "merchant[employees_attributes][#{index}][email]", autocomplete: "off", maxlength: 250, size: nil, data: create_validation_rules(validations[:email])
.control-group
  - if force_superuser_role
    = f.hidden_field :superuser, value: "1"
  - else
    = f.label :superuser, t("admin.labels.superuser")
    = f.check_box :superuser, class: "superuser_checkbox", id: "merchant_employees_attributes_#{index}_superuser", name: "merchant[employees_attributes][#{index}][superuser]"
```

As a function definition embedded in ERB view code is abnormal, http://htmltohaml.com didn't handle it well, and simply regurgitated the entire method into the HAML output.  While this is clearly incorrect, it's a simple matter to correct.

---

If you're being a good net citizen (and as you're already using the tool), you'll report this issue to the developer of http://htmltohaml.com so that he can account for this class of HAML generation issue.

Comment: I will be able to give you 5 more later today, when my votes are replenished.  :D

Comment: can you help me with a similar one i will edit my current question because i can't post a new one 2 days

Comment: @christian The error is because the `end` is not needed for the `content_tag` blocks.  If you simply remove the `end` lines at lines 13, 17, 21, etc, this should work.  When you can post a new question, post this then, and rollback this answer to the original, so that this question and answers are not conflicting.

Answer (score 1):

Best option is to move `create_validation_rules` into a helper or at least make it a `helper_method` in controller.

To keep it in haml - you have to use haml syntax for blocks:

```
- def create_validation_rules(field_rules)
  - if field_rules
    - Hash.[] field_rules.map do |rule|
      - if rule[:value]
        - next ["rule-#{rule[:name]}", rule[:value]]
      - if rule[:msg]
        - next ["msg-#{rule[:name]}", rule[:msg]]
```