# I am confused about the rails scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am confused about the rails Helper scope.

I defined a testpage method in PagesHelper

```
module PagesHelper
  def testpage
    "testpagehelper"
  end
end
```

But why I can use the testpage method in views/users/index.html.erb

```
<h1><%= testpage %> </h1>
```

I suppose the testpage only used in views/pages/index.html.erb?

I think the helper method scope is too broad.

And there is a problem if I defined the same method in the UsersHelper.

```
module UsersHelper
  def testpage
    "testuserhelper"
  end
end
```

there is two testpage in the helper,but the resutl is the view/pages/index.html and the view/users/index.html all use the "testpage" in the UsersHelper?Why?

Answer (score 1):

New Rails apps use `helper :all` in ApplicationController -- which means that all helpers are loaded in all controllers that inherit from ApplicationController. I agree that this is too broad of a scope. So you should change that to `helper :application` and then let each controller pull in just its own helper. Note that each controller will pull in the helper that has its namesake automatically, though, so you don't have to include `helper :user` in UsersController, for example.

Comment: sorry,my problem is the helper scope is all views,even unrelated views.

Comment: I understand and that's the problem I was referring to above too. The controller is respopnsible for pulling in helpers which are then made available to the views for that request. So if you don't load ALL helpers for every request then you won't get all helper methods available in every view. I found this SO post which says the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179865/why-are-all-rails-helpers-available-to-all-views-all-the-time-is-there-a-way-t -- but apparently this is a setting now in Rails >= 3.1.

Comment: thank you very much! I think the DHH thought it is more convenient if the helper is available to all the views,in fact the method 's collide is not big problem if compare to the helper 's DRY.

Answer (score 0):

The different helper modules are just to help with organizing your method. You can use `PageHelper` in non-related views but should you? It's up to the programmer to decide.

Comment: But it will be a problem if there are two same name's method in two different helper?which one is the view can see?

Comment: Method names may collide