# Helper that should not work but still working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `x_helper` and a `y_helper`. As much as I remember, in rails each helper coresponds to a single controller anda single view, and can not be used in a different view.

That excludes `application_helper` which is a general helper.

Still, I have a method in `y_helper`, and when I use that method in a `X view`, it is working, and taking the method from the `y_helper`.

How is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are all Rails helpers available to all views, all the time? Is there a way to disable this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179865/why-are-all-rails-helpers-available-to-all-views-all-the-time-is-there-a-way-t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually by design.  All helpers are loaded for all controllers/views.

You can disable it if you want, in the config/application.rb

```
config.action_controller.include_all_helpers = false
```

Answer (score 0):

That used to be the case in Rails <4. Helpers are modules and so in Rails 4+, all controllers have access to all helpers.  You can revert back to the old behavior by changing your config/environment file:

```
config.action_controller.include_all_helpers = false
```

Comment: But I use rails 3

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/7589901/10955118 this behaviour (all controllers have all helpers by default) has existed since at least Rails 3.1